# Uncaught FoamTree: element has zero dimensions: 522 x 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
if (CarrotSearchFoamTree.supported) {
  var foamtree = new CarrotSearchFoamTree({
    id: "visualization",
    dataObject: {
      groups: [
        { id: "1", label: "Group 1", groups: [
          { id: "1.1", label: "Group 1.1" },
          { id: "1.2", label: "Group 1.2" }
        ]},
        { id: "2", label: "Group 2", groups: [
          { id: "2.1", label: "Group 2.1" },
          { id: "2.2", label: "Group 2.2" }
        ]},
        { id: "3", label: "Group 3", groups: [
          { id: "3.1", label: "Group 3.1" },
          { id: "3.2", label: "Group 3.2" }
        ]},
        { id: "4", label: "Group 4", groups: [
          { id: "4.1", label: "Group 4.1" },
          { id: "4.2", label: "Group 4.2" }
        ]},
        { id: "5", label: "Group 5", groups: [
          { id: "5.1", label: "Group 5.1" },
          { id: "5.2", label: "Group 5.2" }
        ]}
      ]
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log("Visualization not supported.");
}
```

carrot search issue in carrotsearch.foamtree.js :Uncaught FoamTree: element has zero dimensions: 522 x 0.
this is a sample code for carrotsearch any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to  define an HTML element in which FoamTree should be embedded. **The element must have non-zero dimensions**.

see example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="visualization" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
<script src="https://get.carrotsearch.com/foamtree/demo/carrotsearch.foamtree.js"> 
</script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var foamtree = new CarrotSearchFoamTree({
      id: "visualization",
      dataObject: {
        groups: [
          { label: "Your", weight: 1.0 },
          { label: "First", weight: 3.0 },
          { label: "FoamTree", weight: 2.0 },
          { label: "Visualization", weight: 4.0 }
        ]
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```